# Problem with file transfering in java

Tags: java, file-transfer

i have method

```
protected String browsesFile() {        
            String url = null;
            FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
                    .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell(), SWT.NULL);
            // set the filter options
            dialog.setFilterExtensions(new String[] { "*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png" });
            String path = dialog.open();
            if (path != null) {
                File file = new File(path);
                if (file.isFile())
                    url = file.toString();
                else
                    url = file.list().toString();
            }
            return url;
        }// end of method browseFile()
```

It will bring the `url` of the file
. I call it as `text.setText(browsesFile());`. This will bring the url of image that i choose. I want that image to be transfer into `G:\myImage`. For transferring i did the following.

```
    public static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
     if(!destFile.exists()) {
      destFile.createNewFile();
     }

     FileChannel source = null;
     FileChannel destination = null;
     try {
      source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
      destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
      destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
     }
     finally {
      if(source != null) {
       source.close();
      }
      if(destination != null) {
       destination.close();
      }
}}
```

I send By Using the function as

```
File source = new File(text.getText());         
    String url ="G:\\myImage";
    File dest = new File(url);
try {
    copyFile(source, dest);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

i get the error  message as

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: G:\myImage (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

what could be the possible reasong for this? i am using windows 7

Comment: FYI: `transferFrom` transfers _up to_ `source.size()` bytes. According to [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom%28java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel,%20long,%20long%29), it returns "the number of bytes, possibly zero, that were actually transferred ". You may wish to verify precisely how many bytes were _actually_ transferred to avoid subtle bugs.

Comment: The error message seems pretty explicit. Check that the G: drive is mapped correctly on your computer, and that your Java program is running with sufficient privileges to write too it.

Comment: @perception G:\ is my local drive.i have created the folder myImage there.i think it is properly mapped

Comment: Are you trying to write to a file with the same name as the directory?

Comment: Same question as @Captain Giraffe above.

Comment: i want the same same name as source directory, isnt this possible

Comment: is my methods are wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a directory name as your destination thats the source of your error.

You can easily fix this by adding the source filename to the destination by

```
File source = new File(text.getText());         
String url ="G:\\myImage";
File dest = new File(url, source.getName() );
```

Comment: Yes, thanks that absolutley work i appreciate that with a great vote u. i want to ask u another question related to this one. i usually need to work with the url.everytime putting slash is monotonous. i think in some other language Putting @ infront doesnot need to put escape sequence. is there any way in java?